# Apache Spark in r

Tags: r

I am having a problem to connect spark with local instance in r.

I already installed spark version 2.2.0 in r and trying connect with local instance but could not.

> install.packages("sparklyr")
>   library(sparklyr)
>   spark_install(version = "2.2.0")
>   sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

- Using Spark: 2.2.0
  Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
  In addition: Warning message:
  In file(con, "r") :

Answer (score 0):

**I just checked that this is an issue in r-studio**
[Here is the issue](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1432)

Try running these again :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u

If above is done already , then try update and install r-base

sudo apt update

sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev

[**You can check here**](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u)